# Import a python module without .py extension,

Tags: python, import

I agree that there are similar questions,but none serve my purpose.

I have a python script,without a .py extension.

> I can neither change the file name  nor add a symlink. The file name is significant.

I need to import the above mentioned file to another python script

I have tried the following

```
>>> imp.load_source('test','.')
<module 'test' from '.'>
```

and

```
>>> importlib.import_module('test','.')
<module 'test' from '.'>
```

Where the module `test` is just

```
print 'hello world'
```

My requirement is that the import statement works just like it imports if the file was `test.py`,that is,prints `hello world` upon import.

Is there any way to "run" the module imported by using imp or imortlib?

I would like to add that I am talking about a `control` file in the [autotest project](https://github.com/autotest),if it matters.

Comment: i don't think so,I already tried that.I said that the imported module must be executed.That did not happen with imp

Comment: Modules are executed when they are imported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`imp.load_source`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_source)

```
>>> import imp
>>> mod = imp.load_source("test", "test")
hello world
>>> mod.a
1
```

abc:

```
print "hello world"
a = 1
```

Comment: It works, BTW, Why 'foo' is required?I don't see any use of it.

Comment: well,the output does not match mine,I see no `hello world` in my output.

Comment: @RajeevS it works for me, in shell as well as IDLE.

Comment: @RajeevS: You are doing `imp.load_source("test", ".")`, but if you read the documentation, it should be `imp.load_source(name, path)`. You should do `imp.load_source('test', 'test')`.

Comment: Yeah,that was the issue.:)

Comment: Deprecated in Python 3