# module as script without .py in Python?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-module

I want to have a Python file with code called 'foobar' that is meant to be executed as a script when the package is installed as in:

```
$ foobar -i arg1 arg2
```

`foobar` is declared as script in `setup.py`.

The `foobar` file also contains functions/classes that are imported by other modules in the package, so there's a separate file `quux.py` that imports `foobar`:

```
(in `quux.py`):
import mypackage
import mypackage.foobar as foobar
```

How can I keep `foobar` without the `.py` extension and declare it as a script in `setup.py` but still be able to import it from another file as a module? Is this the right answer: [Import a python module without .py extension,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850203/import-a-python-module-without-py-extension)  -- or is there another trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the solution here is to leave `foobar.py` as a module, and have the script be something as simple as:

```
import foobar
foobar.main()
```

If you're installing your module using `setup.py` (and you probably should be), you can also do this via `console_scripts` entry points, like this:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'foobar = foobar:main'
    ],
},
```

This will install a `foobar` command that is roughly equivalent to the stub in the first part of this answer.

Comment: Which of these two solutions is more likely to always work, regardless of pip/easy_install/distribute on user-end? I want the one least likely to break, since both are easy to do code-wise

Comment: Do the `entry_points` method, because it handles os-dependent things under the hood for you.